# Javascript replace method not functioning in checkbox if/else toggle

Tags: javascript, xml, checkbox, replace, toggle

I have a bit of Javascript I'm playing with, which is called by a number of checkboxes and will ideally perform an action (adding and removing &attributeValue=attribID to the URL cumulatively) upon the checkbox being checked/unchecked.

Here's the Javascript:

```
var filterBaseURL = <?="\"".$url."\""?>; /*This is just copying a php variable that contains the base URL defined earlier - all of this works fine*/
var filterFullURL = filterBaseURL;
function filterToggle(attribID)
{
  var elementII = document.getElementById(attribID);
  if(elementII.checked){
     filterFullURL = filterFullURL+"&attributeValue="+attribID;
  }
  else {
     filterFullURL.replace("&attributeValue="+attribID, "");
     alert(filterFullURL);
  }
}
```

So what I'm doing here is attempting to on *check* of a checkbox add that checkbox's attributeValue to the URL, and on *uncheck* of a checkbox, remove that checkbox's attributeValue from the URL. I am using the filterFullURL = filterFullURL+"..." because there are multiple checkboxes and I want all their attributeValues to cumulatively be added to the URL.

All of this is working fine - the only thing that isn't working fine is the else statement action -

```
filterFullURL.replace("&attributeValue="+attribID, "");
```

Here are some example checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="filterToggle('price_range_0_20')" name="Price_Range" value="Below_$20" id="price_range_0_20" /> Below $20
<input type="checkbox" onclick="filterToggle('price_range_20_40')" name="Price_Range" value="$20_-_$40" id="price_range_20_40" /> $20 - $40
<input type="checkbox" onclick="filterToggle('price_range_40_70')" name="Price_Range" value="$40_-_$70" id="price_range_40_70" /> $40 - $70
```

So to recap - I can add the attributeValues of all the checkboxes together, but I can't delete any of them. Any help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you not need to save the output of filterFullURL.replace like filterFullURL = filterFullURL.replace("&attributeValue="+attribID, "")?

Comment: That totally solved it, wow. You're awesome, thanks for catching that, guess this allnighter coding session's starting to catch up with me (will accept your answer when I'm able to in 5 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

There was also an alert missing from the if statement - not sure if that's intentional, but this should operate well for you:

```
var filterBaseURL = <?="\"".$url."\""?>; /*This is just copying a php variable that contains the base URL defined earlier - all of this works fine*/
var filterFullURL = filterBaseURL;
function filterToggle(attribID)
{
  var elementII = document.getElementById(attribID);
  if(elementII.checked){
     filterFullURL = filterFullURL+"&attributeValue="+attribID;
     alert(filterFullURL);
  }
  else {
     filterFullURL = filterFullURL.replace("&attributeValue="+attribID, "");
     alert(filterFullURL);
  }
}
```